# Не работает метод Регистрации

Tags: php

Всем привет. Пытаюсь сделать регистрацию, написал класс:

```
namespace Model\Registration;

require_once 'Db.php';
use Model\Database\Db;

class Registration {

    protected $connection;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->connection = Db::Connect();
    }

    public function Registr() {
        if(isset($_POST['btn'])) {
            if(isset($_POST['email']) !== '' && isset($_POST['login']) !== '' && isset($_POST['password']) !== '') {
                $dbh = $this->connection;
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO users(email, login, password) VALUES (:email, :login, :password)';
                $sqlParams = [':email' => $_POST['email'], ':login' => $_POST['login'], ':password' => $_POST['password']];
                $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
                $sth->execute($sqlParams);
                header('Location: /');
            } else {
                echo 'Заполните все поля <a href="../View/registration.php"><b>Registration</b></a>';
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Из другого файла, пытаюсь вызвать метод Registr

```
<?php 

require 'Model/Registration.php';
use Model\Registration\Registration;

$registration = new Registration();
$registration->Registr();


require 'View/index.php';
```

И ничего не происходит. Код работает только в том случае, если я создаю объект и вызываю нужный метод в том файле, где этот класс написан. Что не так делаю?

Comment: точка входа какой файл?

Comment: ну вот, второй код который я скинул. Объект создаётся, а вот вызов метода показывает null

Comment: зачем вам use Model\Registration\Registration, если вы сделали require?

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); добавьте в начало файла входа, поможет немного